# c++ memcpy int to char buffer

Tags: c++, bit, memcpy

I am trying to write a print function that takes a buffer of any length (in bytes) and prints the bit representation. However, when I use memcpy to copy an int to the buffer something unexpected happens:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  
  unsigned int f = 1;
  
  std::bitset<32> ui(f);
  std::cout << ui << std::endl;
  
  uint8_t* c_f = new uint8_t[sizeof(f)];
  std::memcpy((void*)c_f, (void*)&f, sizeof(f));
  
  for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    std::bitset<8> ua(c_f[i]);
    std::cout << ua << std::endl;
  }
  
}
```

gives:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000001
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

although I would expect:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000001
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Becasuse your machine is *little-endian*?

Comment: Handy reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @MikeCAT Suggested edit: "?" -> "!" :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Unrelated: Since you know the size of the buffer, there is no need for `new`. As a programmer it is in your best interests to avoid `new` wherever possible. Use fixed size automatic allocations or library containers. If neither of those works use a smart pointer. Reach into your toolbox for `new` last. Errr... second last. You should prefer `new` over `malloc`,

Comment: Unrelated: How come you use `sizeof(f)` here: `new uint8_t[sizeof(f)];` but not here `i<4`?

Comment: Btw: You don't necessarily need to create a copy to inspect the data byte by byte: `uint8_t* c_f = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&f); for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(f); i++) {`

Comment: Addendum to above: Any object in C++ can be viewed as an array of bytes ([point 3 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)). The reverse is not true. Often you cannot safely cast a bunch of bytes into an object (there are a bunch of reasons for this, the most common probably being [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)), and this is where you typically deploy `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! very helpful. Best helpful @MikeCAT, fabian and user4581301. This will help me out :)